# Openstack instance Console returning error 1006

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

If you are unable to access your console with Error 1006 through Nova's NoVNC console access, you can find the log in /var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log (Centos 7 location).

In my log, I noticed this error specifically when refreshing the console page:

```
   [root@server ~(keystone_admin)]# tail -f /var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 711, in top_new_client
    self.new_client()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/console/websocketproxy.py", line 132, in new_client
    self.new_websocket_client()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/console/websocketproxy.py", line 72, in new_websocket_client
    tsock = self.socket(host, port, connect=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 180, in socket
    socket.IPPROTO_TCP, flags)
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, you must ensure your server can resolve itself.

Make sure hostname -i returns the right IP, and try pinging your hostname from your server to make sure it knows where it is.

One workaround if there is no DNS yet for your hostname is to put the ip and host in /etc/hosts

For instance, I fixed this by putting the following in /etc/hosts:

192.168.1.46 server